# restrict chrome extension from reading/modifying certain pages

Tags: google-chrome-extension, privacy, restrict

Is there a way to restrict (some) chrome extensions from some pages? i.e to prevent them from reading the content or modifying the pages which might have personal or sensitive data. I realize that this might not be the right forum to ask this but I don't know where else to ask this question.
I don't have any chrome development experience but I am willing to work on this, I just don't know the right approach or if it is even possible with current API.

Comment: Assuming you won't modify the extensions, the only solution is policies or administrative templates, specifically [runtime_blocked_hosts](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3/extension-settings-full).

Comment: Well, you can also open those pages in incognito window - assuming you didn't allow the extensions to run in incognito using a checkbox on chrome://extensions page.